# How to apply start/stop sound method using ToggleButton?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-mediaplayer, android-button

How to apply start/stop function for `ToggleButton` or normal `Button`?

The problem is it doesn't stop/start after the first attempt! It works only once (it should change every time the user clicked the button).

**Music ToggleButton**

```
<ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/music"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="ToggleButton" />
```

**Background Music function**

```
fun BackgroundMusic() {

    val mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sudani)
    mp.start()

    music.setOnClickListener {
        if (mp.isPlaying) {
            mp.stop()
        } else if (!mp.isPlaying) {
            mp.start()
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a deep look into the [MediaPlayer javadoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html).
There you can read something like this:

> Calling stop() stops playback and causes a MediaPlayer in the Started, Paused, Prepared or PlaybackCompleted state to enter the Stopped state.
>
> - Once in the Stopped state, playback cannot be started until prepare() or prepareAsync() are called to set the MediaPlayer object to the Prepared state again.

Basically it means you have to call `prepare()` before you call `start()` again:

```
fun BackgroundMusic() {

    val mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sudani)
    mp.start()

    music.setOnClickListener {
        if (mp.isPlaying) {
            mp.stop()
        } else if (!mp.isPlaying) {
            try {
                mp.prepare()
                mp.start()
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This cool, now it's working ..

I also added : [ mediaplayer.setOnPreparedListener( { mp -> mp.start() })  mp.prepareAsync() ] in case MediaPlayer is not ready.